# How do i make a script that when opened (as an editor) sends an email to themselves? (google docs)

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to send an email from the editor to themselves when an editor opens a google document with google apps script.

I have tried to get a friend to open the document and the code I had did not send them an email.

```
var editors = file.getEditors();
for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
  Logger.log(editors[i].getEmail());
  GmailApp.sendEmail(editors[i].getEmail(), 'How are you?', 'Its snowing.');
}
                   }
```

I expected when the document was opened, it will send an email to them that was sent by themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restrictions on simple triggers, from the Apps Script [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions):

> They cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a
>   simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires
>   authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the
>   Language service, which is anonymous.

The only way you can make this work is if the person opening the document has already authorized the script.